# preg_match no sequence of two or more hypen and apostrophe character

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need to make a name validation. A name only consist of letters (a-z and A-Z), hyphens, apostrophes and spaces; contains no sequence of two or more of the characters hyphen and apostrophe; and starts with a letter. If these constraints are satisfied, then we call the name valid.
So far I have done

```
 if(preg_match("/[^a-zA-Z'-]+/",$testname)) ...
```

But I am not sure how to disallow two or more of the characters hyphen and apostrophe and make it start only with a letter. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Which Assignment was this for? I have the same requirement. Web Programming Uni of Liverpool

Answer (score 0):

This one meets your needs:

```
/^(?:[a-z]+[-' ]?)+$/
```

**Explanation:**

```
/               : regex delimiter
  ^             : begining of string
    (?:         : start non capture group
      [a-z]+    : 1 or more letter
      [-' ]?    : optionaly 1 of these characters, hyphen or apostrophe or space
    )+          : end group, 1 or more times
  $             : end of string
/i              : regex delimiter + modifier case insensitive
```

If you want the name ends with a letter:

```
/^(?:[a-z]+[-' ]?)+[a-z]$/i
```

If you want to match names in any language:

```
/^(?:\p{L}+[-' ]?)+\p{L}$/
```

where `\p{L}` stands for any letter in any language

*In fine* I suggest you to read this: https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/